# How to get a DocumentFilter to work with a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, keylistener, documentfilter

I tried this before with a DocumentListener, but that gave me too may issues with editing the Document after I heard something. Now I'm trying to do the same with a DocumentFilter, which appears to be working.

```
public class InputField extends JComboBox<String>{

//for finding suggestions
private SuggestionFinder _finder;
//the model to use for adding items
private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> _model;

public InputField(SuggestionFinder finder){
    super();
    _model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    this.setModel(_model);
    maximumRowCount = 5;
    this.setEditable(true);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(300, 75);
    this.setMinimumSize(d);
    this.setMaximumSize(d);
    _finder = finder;
    Component edComp = editor.getEditorComponent();
    Document document = ((JTextComponent)edComp).getDocument();
    if (document instanceof PlainDocument) {
     ((PlainDocument) document).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
              String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("1");
            Document d = fb.getDocument();
            giveSuggestions(d.getText(0, d.getLength()));
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
              throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("2");
            Document d = fb.getDocument();
            giveSuggestions(d.getText(0, d.getLength()));
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
              String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
            System.out.println("3");
            Document d = fb.getDocument();
            giveSuggestions(d.getText(0, d.getLength()));
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
        }
     });
  }
}

private void giveSuggestions(String word){
    System.out.println(word);
    _model.removeAllElements();
    if (word.equals("")){
        this.hidePopup();
    }
    else{
        this.showPopup();
        /*List<String> suggs = _finder.getSuggestions(word);
        for (int i = 1; i <= suggs.size(); i++){
            _model.addElement(suggs.get(i-1));
        }*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            System.out.println("adding");
            _model.addElement("" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    //instantiate a finder, how I do this isn't really relevant to my issue
    InputField field = new InputField(finder);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(field);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something tells me that you don't want to do this, that instead you really want to use a DocumentFilter. For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class DocFilterEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();      
      InputField2 field2 = new InputField2();

      panel.add(field2.getCombo());

      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class InputField2 {
   String[] foo = {"1", "2", "3"};
   private JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>(foo);

   public InputField2() {
      combo.setEditable(true);
      Object editorComponent = combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
      Document document = ((JTextComponent)editorComponent).getDocument();

      if (document instanceof PlainDocument) {
         ((PlainDocument) document).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                  String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

               Document doc = fb.getDocument();
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
               System.out.println("Original String: " + sb.toString());
               sb.insert(offset, string);
               System.out.println("New String:      " + sb.toString());

               super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
                  throws BadLocationException {

               Document doc = fb.getDocument();
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
               System.out.println("Original String: " + sb.toString());
               sb.delete(offset, offset + length);
               System.out.println("New String:      " + sb.toString());

               super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                  String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

               Document doc = fb.getDocument();
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
               System.out.println("Original String: " + sb.toString());
               sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
               System.out.println("New String:      " + sb.toString());

               super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
         });
      }
   }

   public JComponent getCombo() {
      return combo;
   }
}
```

**Edit** as I mentioned yesterday in your previous post.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it and it's now catching the key presses correctly. However, as I have edited my question above to explain, I'm getting a strange infinite loop once I type a second letter. The error message is saying that that it's occurring at the line where I say "this.showPopup()", do you know why this might be?

Comment: Actually I feel like this is an error in some code I was given by somebody else to work with, thanks for the help! I'll respond here again if I have any followup questions.

Comment: Never mind, it's definitely an issue here. For some reason the first letter types and then the next letter causes the program to crash. Commenting out the 'this.showPopup()' line doesn't help either.